# Div center aligned between two floats not working in Safari after media query.

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a left and right float div. I have a box in the middle that is float none and is set to be centered between the two floats. If the window is too small i want to drop the right div under everything.

This works fine in firefox, but in safari it works initially, but fails after the resize.

Any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/bzr49/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left">hey</div>
<div class="middle">hey</div>
<div class="right">hey</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;    
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: yellow;
}

.middle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 472px) {
    .middle {float: none;margin: 0 auto;}
    .right {clear: none;float: right;margin-left: 16px;}
}
```

Comment: in the fiddle when i resize it the green box drops below the red and yellow. can you post a screenshot of what yours looks like and what you want it to look like?

Comment: the same issue seems to occur in Chrome. The green box drops down when you scale down but does not move back up on scale up. It is fine again when you reload. In my experience webkit browsers can be a bit buggy on their media queries when resizing. Don't forget that only we developers do this for testing, no real user plays with his viewport size like we do. I wouldn't bother coding around browser bugs!

Comment: @AnindyaBasu Yes when you resize it drops down, but when you resize it bigger again it does not move back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;    
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: yellow;
}

.middle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 472px) {
    .middle {float: none;margin: 0 auto;}
    .right {clear: none;float: right;margin-left: 16px;}
}
```

Setting the right div to `display: inline-block` and `float:left` fixed it for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/bzr49/7/